# Is it ever valid to use only 1 wire from each cable(14/2) to connect an electrical circuit?

Tags: electrical

I was replacing a bathroom fan in my house ( built 1957) and I got curious about how it was wired, so I thought I would ask here.

Basically there was two separate cables going to the fan

1 that had only the black exposed going to the fan and the rest were electrical taped off

1 that had only the white exposed going to the fan

well technically the ground was also partially exposed, but it wasn't wired to anything when I disconnected the old fan.

the black isn't electrical taped off on this one, should I do that?

Just curious if this is a normal pattern in a circuit with only using 1 of each type of wire from 2 different cables.

I already hooked the new fan up with the same wiring as it used before (only black and white hooked up, no ground) and its working but I figured I'd ask.

Pic related.

[image: wiring pic]

Answer (score 4):

The live and neutral wire for any outlet (receptacle, fan, lighting etc...) must be bundled in the same conduit or cable.

Keeping the currents equal in both and keeping the area between the conductors small prevents electro magnetic radiation and thus EMI (electro magnetic ingress) into other equipment or conductors.

Using one wire from one cable for live and another wire from another cable for neutral can cause EMI into radio or audio equipment, and at very high currents (likely not the case for your bathroom fan) there may be induction heating or induction of stray voltages into nearby metallic objects.

Any unused wires should be taped off at both ends.

Answer (score 1):

If I had to guess your house is old and originally had knob and tube wiring where the hot and neutral are run separately.

When the bathroom you are working on was put in the person renovating it probably cut back the knob and tube to a junction box but since the knob and tube neutral and hot typically take very different pathways through houses they fed the wires back to different spots.

Comment: Seems like knob and tube was installed with into the 1950s...  your house would be at the end of when you'd expect something like that.